# Is there a circularity in the definition of binary relations?

Tags: set-theory, definition, relations

In set theory, binary relations are defined as sets of ordered pairs. However, this relies on the binary relation $\in$ of set theory. So, is the definition of binary relations somewhat circular? Or am I just misunderstanding something? Perhaps someone can clarify this point for me.

Comment: $\in$ is not a "binary relation" as you defined it. There is no set whose elements are all the ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x\in y.$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748256/how-elements-are-defined-in-axiomatic-set-theory

Comment: $\in$ is a primitive notion in set theory, so it has no definition within the theory. There are only axioms about how the symbol can be used that imply a kind-of definition when humans read them.

Comment: The resolutions above are correct, but note that even without them this wouldn’t be evidence for circularity. General ideas are defined in terms of specific instances all the time (e.g. in analysis, an open set is defined in terms of open intervals). One would need to look into the actual definition of the special case (or lack thereof in this case, as noted above) to see if the general idea is actually used.

Comment: But,@AnneBauval, $\in$ **can** be considered a binary relation as a subset of, say, ${\bf N} \times 2^{\bf N}$.

Comment: ∈, = are logical symbols in set theory, not binary Relations, they aren't even sets, they are primitive notions which let us form atomic formula ( x = y OR x∈y) 
They pre-exist the notion of binary relation. Binary Relations are defined once you have the Axiom of Replacement, Union, Pairing, Extentionality, Existence. But, =, ∈ make sense in any Universe of Set Theory ( any axioms) because they are part of the language. We think of them as Atomic, because we don't/cant define them in terms of simpler notions. They are the "building blocks" of Set Theory

Comment: I don’t dispute that, @MichaelCarey. But there is also nothing stopping one from considering the subset $E \subset {\bf N} \times 2^{\bf N}$ containing exactly those $(n,S)$ for which  $n \in S$. And that $E$ is a binary relation. I hasten to add that this does not work—for reasons that one hopes are obvious—to **define** set membership.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Sorry, I don't want to make it seen like I disagree with you. You are completely Correct. Kunen, called =, ∈ "pseudo-relations" precisely for the reasons you make. We can form a very natural binary relation out of them, so natural that its common to not even use a different symbol, I've had professors say: We can think of ∈ as a duel use symbol, as elementhood, and as a relation. Where the relation interpretation, ∈ is a shorthand, for the relation you more formally defined.